# Replace the attribute value of all shapes with specific value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I'm pretty green when it comes to QGIS. I have a shapefile with a bunch of fields and farm codes of whats growing in them. However there are like 600 of them, so I want to go through and simplify. So  All values that represent a type of fruit tree will just be one value.

How can I implement a function along the lines of '`IF 'field value' = x,y,z THEN = Q?`'

and where would I implement that? Somewhere in the attribute table right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `if("fieldname" in ('x','y','z'),'value if true','value if false')` in the attribute table via field calculator. Note that `''` are used for string values. If you have numeric values use the same expression without `''`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "[Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator)" [image] in QGIS.

[image]

- Open "Field Calculator"
- Enter `Output field name`
- Select `String` as `Output field type`
- Set the `Output field length`
- Add an expression like below: (use double quote (`"`) for `field_name`, apostrophe (`'`) for `string`s)

  ```
  if("field_name" IN ('x', 'y', 'z'), 'Q?', '')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Field Calculator".

[image: Field Calculator]

Then, just build your expression in the left-hand box in the new window.